# file_exists($img) and @getimagesize($img) are always returning false

Tags: php

I have a script that lets users upload an own header image for specific pages of my website. To check if the user has uploaded an image I use `file_exists($img)`. But the function always returns false.

I've also tried using `@getimagesize($img)` which didn't work either. When I use `echo "<img src='".$img."'>` though, the picture shows without problem.

Maybe there's a mistake in my code, I don't know. Or maybe it has something to do with security issues? I tried using different files and chmod() though. Please help.

Here is my code:

```php
define('PATH', '/root/');
define('LAYOUT', 'header1');

//This is always returning false
if (defined('LAYOUT') && (file_exists(PATH.'img/header/'.LAYOUT.'.png') OR 
    file_exists(PATH.'img/header/'.LAYOUT.'.jpg'))) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

//This is also returning false
if (defined('LAYOUT') && (@getimagesize($img)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

//This is showing the picture
echo "<img style='width: 100%;' src='".PATH."img/header/".LAYOUT.".png'>";
```

EDIT: I solved it by using `file_exists(__DIR__ . '\\www\\img\\header\\'.LAYOUT.'.png')`. Thank you!

Comment: can you tell us which operating system are you working on?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and XAMPP if you mean that.
ah, maybe backslashes instead of / ? edit: didn't do the trick

Comment: I guess it is because of the backslashes. By the way there is no path as `/root/` in windows. it should be something like: `C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\blabla\\root\\...` Note the double backslashes as you have to escape it

Comment: That's working! However, it's not very useful since it's only working on my computer like this and I have to upload it... Is there any other way (maybe relative) to check a file?

Comment: You can use native php constants to figure that out. Please refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php. So doing `'.' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` should address the current folder of the script. you can get some relative path using that. Note that DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR means '\\' in windows and '/' in linux

Comment: I would highly recommend using docker. It will save you tons of headaches plus you can deploy it virtually anywhere without having to have concerns like that